# Perl multiline regex in windows

Tags: regex, perl

I'm stuck with this scenario, I have this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/z0WoN0/1)

*Input added here for clarity:

```
181221533;MG;3;1476729;<vars>  <vint>    <name>mtest</name> <storedPrecedure>f_sc_mtest</SP>    <base>M_data</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeMS>17</timeMS>    <ttidr>abc</ttidr>  <base>S</base>    <valor>0</valor>  </vint>  </vars>;889;6;85;112;01/01/2019;29/05/2019 17:17:48
182652972;MG;6314429;740484;<vars>  <vint>    <name>mtest</name>    <sP>f_sc_mtest</sP> <base>sscy</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeMS>16</timeMS>    <ttidr>abc</Idtype>    <base>S</base>    <valor>4</valor>  </vint></vars>;-1;8;57217;57228;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:20:48
182652984;ModeloSP;6314429;740484;<vars>  <vint>     <name>tc_p_act</name>    <sP>rndom_name</sP>    <base>sscyo</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeMS>0</timeMS>    <Idtype>XYZ</Idtype>    <base>O</base>  </vint>
</vars>;0;;0;41;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:31:22

182652988;ModeloSP;6314429;740484;<vars>  <vint>     <name>tc_p_act</name>    <sP>rndom_name</sP>    <base>sscyo</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeProcess>1</timeProcess>    <Idtype>XYZ</Idtype>    <base>O</base>  </vint>
</vars>;0;;0;85;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:37:36
```

And I want to implement this regex in perl with multiline support because as you can see in the sample, there are line breaks in records and this regex searchs 'incomplete' lines (and the extra line) and fixes them (one record/line should end with a datetime)

this is what I'm attempting with perl:

```
perl.exe -0777 -i -pe "s/(?m)^(.*)(>)([\n]+)(<)(.*)([\n]+)(\s*)$/$1$2    $4$5/igs" "sample.txt"
```

And doesn't seem to work, I keep getting the same text file. I'm using perl inside a portable GIT installation (v5.34.0)

Is there something I'm missing?

edit: This is how the output should look like:

```
181221533;MG;3;1476729;<vars>  <vint>    <name>mtest</name> <storedPrecedure>f_sc_mtest</SP>    <base>M_data</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeMS>17</timeMS>    <ttidr>abc</ttidr>  <base>S</base>    <valor>0</valor>  </vint>  </vars>;889;6;85;112;01/01/2019;29/05/2019 17:17:48
182652972;MG;6314429;740484;<vars>  <vint>    <name>mtest</name>    <sP>f_sc_mtest</sP> <base>sscy</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeMS>16</timeMS>    <ttidr>abc</Idtype>    <base>S</base>    <valor>4</valor>  </vint></vars>;-1;8;57217;57228;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:20:48
182652984;ModeloSP;6314429;740484;<vars>  <vint>     <name>tc_p_act</name>    <sP>rndom_name</sP>    <base>sscyo</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeMS>0</timeMS>    <Idtype>XYZ</Idtype>    <base>O</base>  </vint>    </vars>;0;;0;41;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:31:22
182652988;ModeloSP;6314429;740484;<vars>  <vint>     <name>tc_p_act</name>    <sP>rndom_name</sP>    <base>sscyo</base>    <dataType>I</dataType>    <timeProcess>1</timeProcess>    <Idtype>XYZ</Idtype>    <base>O</base>  </vint>    </vars>;0;;0;85;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:37:36
```

Comment: Please include the input to the question, formatted as code.

Comment: @choroba done, input added

Comment: You're using the wrong flags. In the regex101 link you're using `/gm`, but in the Perl command you're using `/igs`. `/i` is not needed because your expression is case insensitive as is. `/s` probably is not what you need either considering there's a line break before `</vars>`. `/gm` seems to me like the correct flags.

Comment: Help me out to parse input-vs-desired output ... you just want to remove the extra blank lines?

Comment: @Jesse tried this, still nothing, I mean I keep getting the same as the input: perl.exe -0777 -i -pe "s/(?m)^(.*)(>)([\n]+)(<)(.*)([\n]+)(\s*)$/$1$2    $4$5/gm" "sample.txt"

Comment: @zdim yes, the extra blank lines, but also the xml part has line breaks; every record/line should finish with a datetime field, I added the desired output in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is having newlines in the wrong place, either multiple newlines in a row, or before a `<`, you may get away with something simple like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$str =~ s/\n(?=[<\n])//g;
print $str;

__DATA__
181221533;<valor>0</valor></vars>;889;6;85;112;01/01/2019;29/05/2019 17:17:48
182652972;</vars>;-1;8;57217;57228;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:20:48
182652984;</vint>
</vars>;0;;0;41;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:31:22

182652988; </vint>
</vars>;0;;0;85;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:37:36
```

(I shortened the input to make it readable)

Output:

```
181221533;<valor>0</valor></vars>;889;6;85;112;01/01/2019;29/05/2019 17:17:48
182652972;</vars>;-1;8;57217;57228;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:20:48
182652984;</vint></vars>;0;;0;41;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:31:22
182652988; </vint></vars>;0;;0;85;01/01/2019;06/06/2019 22:37:36
```

Comment: that's it, for windows compatibility, this works: s/\r\n(?=[<\r\n])//g

Comment: This was made in windows. I'm not sure about the details, but there's some Perl magic involved about the line endings. I never have to supply more than `\n` in windows.

Comment: You can always use `\R` for a [universal](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/06/the-r-generic-line-ending/) notion of a line ending.

Answer (score 3):

Capture the whole record and replace all newlines in it by a space, using another regex inside the replacement part (courtesy of `/e` modifier). Then replace all multiple newlines by a single one

```
perl.exe -0777 -wpe'
    s{ (?:^|\R)\K (\d{9}; .*? \s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) }{$1 =~ s/\n+/ /r}segx; s{\n+}{\n}g
' file.txt
```

I consider a "record" to be: `[0-9]{9};` on line/file beginning, then all up to and including a timestamp after spaces.  The details for beginning and end of record should protect against accidental matching of possible unexpected patterns inside those tags.

This is cumbersome but it captures the record correctly I hope, even if some details change.

---

Apparently the above fails on Windows as it stands, while it is confirmed to work on Linux (the only system I can try it on right now).

The issue must be in newlines -- so try replacing `\n` in matches with `\R` or `\r\n`.  In particular in the regex embedded in the replacement part. Or, to be safe and perhaps portable, replace `\n` with `(\r?\n)` (so the carriage return character is optional, need not be there in order to match).

So either

```
s{ (?:^|\R)\K (\d{9}; .*? \s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) }{$1 =~ s/\R+/ /r}segx; s{\R+}{\r\n}g
```

or

```
s{ (?:^|\R)\K(\d{9};.*?\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) }{$1 =~ s/(\r\n)+/ /r}segx; s{(\r\n)+}{\r\n}g
```

But `\R` should match it on Windows, so you should be able to use `\R` for matching and `\r\n` when needed in replacements. See it under [Misc in perlbackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#Misc)

---

Better yet, if it works, is to use [PerlO layers](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO). Normally a Windows build of Perl adds the `:crlf` layer by default but that seems not to be the case here.

In a one-liner try:

```
perl.exe -0777 -Mopen=:std,IO,:crlf -wpe'...'
```

Or, use the "one-liner" as a normal program, without file-processing switches, and set this up via [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open)  and open a file manually

```
perl -wE'use open IO => ":crlf"; $_ = do { local $/; <> }; s{...}{...}; say' file
```

With layers set like this (in either way) use the regex with `\n`.

Comment: Maybe I'm lost but this command only adds a space right before the <vars> tag, at lines 4 and 7 of the input, am I doing something wrong? perl.exe -0777 -wpe "s{ (?:^|\R)\K (\d{9}; .*? \s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) }{$1 =~ s/\n+/ /r}segx; s{\n+}{\n}g" "test.txt" > salso1.txt

Comment: Hm, I just copy-pasted it here and it does as intended, removing all extra newlines inside records, and collapses multiple newlines between records.  So it prints, on each line: `181221533;` (or such), followed by stuff up to ` 22:31:22` (or such).  The only problem I can think of is that this is on a linux terminal here. Perhaps try to replace all `\n` in matches with `\R`, or some such (for Windows)? Or add `\r`, like `\n\(r?)+`

Comment: yes, it is a windows issue indeed, I tried in linux but unfortunately I need to do it in windows. Could you please highlight which characters of the pattern should I try to replace for windows context?

Comment: I'd expect that to be about newlines then.  I added a comment to the end of the answer, I hope it's clear?  Sorry I can't resolve it myself right now as I can't get my hands on a Windows box here

Comment: @NatyBizz Added explicit code with it to the answer

Answer (score 2):

This seems to produce the wanted output:

```
perl.exe -0777 -pe "s: *\n(?=</):    :g;s/\n+/\n/g"
```

- The first substitution replaces whitespace followed by a newline before `</` by four spaces.
- The second substitution replaces multiple newlines by a single one. You can also replace it by a transliteration: `tr/\n//s`, the `/s` "squeezes" the newlines.